# design a knob - radial distribution lines

Tags: c++, user-interface, geometry

Assuming I have a draw function in C++ to draw lines like this:

```
drawLine(float startX>, float startY, float endX, float endY);
```

What would be the formula to draw radial distribution lines around a knob like in the picture below:

[image]

Ok, this code is working fine:

```
float length, x1, y1, x2, y2;
length = 40;
float radius = 80;
int sliderSteps = 8;
float rotaryStartAngle = radians(-110);
float rotaryEndAngle = radians(110);
float theta = rotaryStartAngle;
//distance between segments
float angleAmount = (rotaryEndAngle - rotaryStartAngle) / sliderSteps;

for(int i =0; i<=sliderSteps; i++){
x1 = width/2 + cos(theta)*radius;
y1 = height/2 + sin(theta)*radius;
x2 = x1+cos(theta)*length;
y2 = y1+sin(theta)*length;
theta += angleAmount;
line(x1, y1, x2, y2); 
}
```

Comment: something like this: 
            for(int i=0; i<slider.getMaximum(); i++){
                g.drawLine(cos(angle) *rotaryStartAngle, sin(angle) *rotaryStartAngle, cos(angle) *rotaryEndAngle, sin(angle) *rotaryEndAngle);
            }

Comment: Try a loop from 0 to 6.28 in steps of 0.2 as angle. Then muliply with a radius of say 50, your rotaryAngle variables don't make any sense to me. Add the position of the knob as offset before drawing.